# Expand heap size or allocate seperate heap for different Forms in .netCF

Tags: c#, user-interface, compact-framework

I'm working on an internal image viewer for an application, and some of the images that I'm loading up can be pretty big.

[I read a wonderful article about loading big images (Thanks Chris!)](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2010/10/13/LoadingPartsOfLargeImagesInTheCompactFramework.aspx), but since it's internal to another application, it usually won't start with enough memory to allocate a buffer image large enough for the visible portion of the image.  It runs in a different Form (one that is full screen w/o the startbar and the notification bar, where as the application Form has both) and so I would like to know if there is any way to allocate a heap specific for that Form that is seperate from the other?  Or is there any way that I can expand the heap beyond 32mb?

Thanks for any help!